# How can I vertically align divs inside a grid layout?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-grid

Why are divs inside a `grid` layout not aligned by default?

How can I align them?

```css
.dpNav{
width:50%;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
text-align:center;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div class='dpNav' id='dpNav'>
<div class='yearTitle' id='yearTitle'>2019</div>
<div class='btnYear' id='btnYear'>&#x267B;</div>
<div></div>
<div class='monthTitle' id='monthTitle'>JAN</div>
<div class='btnMonth' id='btnMonth'>&#x267B;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: upvoted this because you included a working code snippet :) are you wanting to put each div above each other vertically?

Comment: @YvonneAburrow, no I want the same top and bottom margin on each grid child.

Answer (score 1):

add `align-items:center;`

```css
.dpNav{
width:50%;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
text-align:center;
background:gold;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='dpNav' id='dpNav'>
<div class='yearTitle' id='yearTitle'>2019</div>
<div class='btnYear' id='btnYear'>&#x267B;</div>
<div></div>
<div class='monthTitle' id='monthTitle'>JAN</div>
<div class='btnMonth' id='btnMonth'>&#x267B;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm... top margin on symbols are a pixel or two in plus.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dpNav{
width:50%;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
text-align:center;
vertical-align: middle;
background:gold;
padding-bottom: 2px
}

.text {
 padding-top: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<div class='dpNav' id='dpNav'>
<div class='yearTitle text' id='yearTitle'>2019</div>
<div class='btnYear' id='btnYear'>&#x267B;</div>
<div></div>
<div class='monthTitle text' id='monthTitle'>JAN</div>
<div class='btnMonth' id='btnMonth'>&#x267B;</div>
</div>
```

if you don't like my tweaks to the padding, you could also put the contents inside a span and set the CSS for that to `vertical-align: middle`.

Comment: And could someone explain - why `Dogukan's` solution is not perfect - why I need additional `padding` and `spans` - why the divs are not aligned by default?

Comment: it seems the default setting is for the text to be aligned to the bottom rather than the center. The recycle icons are a slightly different height to the text.

Answer (score 1):

Adding in `align-items:center` on the parent container will achieve what you are looking for.  The reason why it isn't set by default is to give the user control of its placement.  [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) has a really in-depth breakdown of the different ways you can align items in a grid.

```css
.dpNav{
width:50%;
display:grid;
align-items:center;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
text-align:center;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div class='dpNav' id='dpNav'>
<div class='yearTitle' id='yearTitle'>2019</div>
<div class='btnYear' id='btnYear'>&#x267B;</div>
<div></div>
<div class='monthTitle' id='monthTitle'>JAN</div>
<div class='btnMonth' id='btnMonth'>&#x267B;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for great link to css-tricks